# How to manually renew Apple Developer program with different credit card?

Tags: apple-id, developer-program

I want to manually renew my Apple Developer program with a different credit card then what's on file.

https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/

> You can renew starting 30 days before the expiration date of your
>   existing membership or any time after it expires. Your expiration date
>   is available in your account on the developer website. To renew, sign
>   in to your account with the Apple ID you used to enroll, and click the
>   "Renew Membership” button. If your membership is still active when you
>   renew, your new membership will activate as soon as your current
>   membership expires and you will receive two (2) new TSIs.

I signed into my account but I cannot locate the "Renew Membership" button. What page in my developer account is this on?

Answer (score 2):

Login to the Apple Developer site: developer.apple.com.

Apple uses your account's default Apple Store credit card.

On the left-side menu select `Membership`.

Scroll to the bottom of the page to `Auto-renew membership` section.  This is where the `Auto-renew Membership` checkbox is located.

On the right-side of this row there's a link named `Edit default debit/credit card`.

A new browser window will, probably, pop up and require you to log into your account again.  Alternatively, you can just go to the page to change your account's credit card.  I go thru the developer site to ensure this is updated correctly (because I'm paranoid).

Scroll down to `Payment & Shipping` section.  Edit your card there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This got me halfway there. If you uncheck "Auto-renew membership" then you get the "Renew membership" button on the top of that page where you can use a new credit card without changing the default one to renew.

Comment: I'm glad you found the button.  I wrote my answer that way because you said you wanted to manually renew with a different credit card so I thought you meant you wanted to change the one Apple currently had.